# make Dynamic JSONArray from Exiting Data in React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, timeline

I am new to React-native

can any one tell me how to make a dynamic array from existing api data?

for example , I have an array like this:

```
[
  {name: 'ajay', time: '09:00', class: 'one',title: 'Archery Training', description: 'The Beginner Archery and Beginner Crossbow course does not require you to bring any equipment, since everything you need will be provided for the course. ', circleColor: '#009688',lineColor:'#009688'},
  {name: 'vijay',time: '10:45', class: 'two',title: 'Play Badminton', description: 'Badminton is a racquet sport played using racquets to hit a shuttlecock across a net.'},
  {name: 'zoya',time: '12:00', class: 'six',title: 'Lunch'},
  {name: 'prem',time: '14:00',class: 'five', title: 'Watch Soccer', description: 'Team sport played between two teams of eleven players with a spherical ball. ',lineColor:'#009688'},
  {name: 'ram',time: '16:30',class: 'ten', title: 'Go to Fitness center', description: 'Look out for the Best Gym & Fitness Centers around me :)', circleColor: '#009688'}
]
```

now I want to convert it in to like this:

```
[
  {time: '09:00', title: 'Archery Training', description: 'The Beginner Archery and Beginner Crossbow course does not require you to bring any equipment, since everything you need will be provided for the course. ', circleColor: '#009688',lineColor:'#009688'},
  {time: '10:45', title: 'Play Badminton', description: 'Badminton is a racquet sport played using racquets to hit a shuttlecock across a net.'},
  {time: '12:00', title: 'Lunch'},
  {time: '14:00', title: 'Watch Soccer', description: 'Team sport played between two teams of eleven players with a spherical ball. ',lineColor:'#009688'},
  {time: '16:30', title: 'Go to Fitness center', description: 'Look out for the Best Gym & Fitness Centers around me :)', circleColor: '#009688'}
]
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi you can write javascript that ist the point from React-Native.

in that case i would create a function, that takes the data and return the new array. i just made an example for your case. keep in mind that working with data from any API could be more dificult than this example. so if you really get an Array that should be converted in a new one, it would be like that..

```js
var yourAPIData = [
  {name: 'ajay', time: '09:00', class: 'one',title: 'Archery Training', description: 'The Beginner Archery and Beginner Crossbow course does not require you to bring any equipment, since everything you need will be provided for the course. ', circleColor: '#009688',lineColor:'#009688'},
  {name: 'vijay',time: '10:45', class: 'two',title: 'Play Badminton', description: 'Badminton is a racquet sport played using racquets to hit a shuttlecock across a net.'},
  {name: 'zoya',time: '12:00', class: 'six',title: 'Lunch'},
  {name: 'prem',time: '14:00',class: 'five', title: 'Watch Soccer', description: 'Team sport played between two teams of eleven players with a spherical ball. ',lineColor:'#009688'},
  {name: 'ram',time: '16:30',class: 'ten', title: 'Go to Fitness center', description: 'Look out for the Best Gym & Fitness Centers around me :)', circleColor: '#009688'}
]

const convertDataFromAPI = (data) => {
 var newArr = [];
 for ( var a = 0; a < data.length; a++){
 var myObject = {};
 data[a].time ? myObject['time'] = data[a].time : null
 data[a].title ? myObject['title'] = data[a].title : null
 data[a].description ? myObject['description'] = data[a].description : null
 data[a].circleColor ? myObject['circleColor'] = data[a].circleColor : null
 data[a].lineColor ? myObject['lineColor'] = data[a].lineColor : null
    newArr.push(myObject)
  }

  return newArr
}

console.log(convertDataFromAPI(yourAPIData))
```

Additionally you could  install `axios.` it helps you to make hppt requests. and if you need to convert the data into a json type, it will be easier for the subsequent data handling. keep in mind objects must be processed in a different way than arrays in the future convertDataFromArray function.

```
axios.get(request)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => convertDataFromAPI(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
```

i hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the easier way.

Here is how I do using lodash library.

First, install it.

```
npm i --save lodash
```

Then import in your application.

```
import { omit, map } from 'lodash'
```

Then here is to make that array object.

```
const data = [
   {name: 'ajay', time: '09:00', class: 'one',title: 'Archery Training', description: 'The Beginner Archery and Beginner Crossbow course does not require you to bring any equipment, since everything you need will be provided for the course. ', circleColor: '#009688',lineColor:'#009688'},
   {name: 'vijay',time: '10:45', class: 'two',title: 'Play Badminton', description: 'Badminton is a racquet sport played using racquets to hit a shuttlecock across a net.'},
   {name: 'zoya',time: '12:00', class: 'six',title: 'Lunch'},
   {name: 'prem',time: '14:00',class: 'five', title: 'Watch Soccer', description: 'Team sport played between two teams of eleven players with a spherical ball. ',lineColor:'#009688'},
   {name: 'ram',time: '16:30',class: 'ten', title: 'Go to Fitness center', description: 'Look out for the Best Gym & Fitness Centers around me :)', circleColor: '#009688'}
]  

const newData = map(data, (obj) => {
  const mappedObj = omit(obj, ['name', 'class'])
  return mappedObj
})
```

Let me know if it is work or not